# BCP utility incorrect syntax

Tags: sql-server, azure, bcp, sql-server-2014

What is incorrect about this syntax?

```
bcp transitschedule in calendar_dates.txt -T -f calenar_dates.fmt -F 2
```

I have tried this through sqlcmd and SSMS to a database on Azure.  When I run the command I get:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'in'.

Yet, the examples [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) are not very much different syntactically.  If I add database name or schema name error shifts towards the period.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like SQLCMD, BCP is a stand-alone command-prompt utility that must be invoked from a command prompt.  If the source text and format files reside on your client, you'll need to add the -S -U and -P parameters like you do with SQLCMD.  For example:

```
bcp databasename.schemaname.transitschedule in calendar_dates.txt -f calenar_dates.fmt -F 2 /S azure-database-server /U azure-database_login /P azure-database-password
```

Comment: and when I do exactly as you've described, I get error: SQLState = 37000, NativeError = 40607
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Windows logins are
 not supported in this version of SQL Server.  The username I am specifying is of the form form username@server.

Comment: @KlausNji I copied your original command and overlooked omitting the -T parameter.  Remove the -T and you should be good.

Comment: that works better, than you.  Getting other errors now but I should be able to resolve these.